# How can I automatically create an email address for my website members?

Tags: php, mysql, email

How can I automatically create an email address for my website members and forward the mail to their own email address.

eg.

1. john123 signs up to my members site.
2. script automatically creates email address john123@mydomain.com
3. mail to john123@mydomain.com goes to johns email address: john123@hotmail.com

Comment: This depends entirely on your server setup. In some cases your can have your mail server read your email address information from a MySQL database. If you're setting up your own server from scratch, you should be able to accomplish this, if you're in a shared hosting environment, it's unlikely to happen.

Answer (score 2):

If i remember this correctly, this is how i did it. This is not how you envision it to happen though.

1 : Instead of bouncing emails which were sent to a wrong email addy, i routed them to a PHP script.

2 : The script parsed the username part in the "To" field and checked in DB, if match found, get the real email

3 : Re-mail the email to real address.