# How can I automatically create an email address for anyone who signs up at my website?

Tags: java, php, email

I know that just about the same thing was asked here: [How can I...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051971/how-can-i-automatically-create-an-email-address-for-my-website-members) but I would like to use Google's servers because of blacklisting, is there any way for me to do this?

Basically how can I have Google's servers route/forward the email to a PHP script?

Also, it would be very useful to me if someone has the PHP code itself (if anyone has the script/code in any other programming language then I can do that to).

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Google Apps Enterprise, which has an API for creating users.

Alternatively, you can set all email to go to a single catch-all address and read the `To:` field when checking email.

Either way, you'll need to read the email using a POP or IMAP client in PHP.

Comment: That's what I thought but I was not sure, as far as I know you can use all API functions on a business account.

I could find no examples but is there a way to edit the account settings so that it forwards the email?

Comment: Settings, Email, Catch-all address

Comment: What I meant is if there is a way to have it send the email to the script, is there?

Comment: To rephrase: pipe the email to a script.

Comment: AFAIK, Gmail won't do that.  You can probably find an MX server that does, and use that instead of or with Google Apps.

Comment: So I guess I can't do that, through Google's API can I change the individual user's settings to forward all email to another email address?

Comment: This: http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/email_settings/developers_guide_protocol.html#GA_email_forwarding_main I have to go and will be back in the morning thanks again for your time, I will try to post the final solution here.